# Почему не работает клик у awt.Robot?

Tags: java, awt

Есть код который по задумке должен выделять текст так как это делает человек мышкой. Но почему-то он не срабатывает, сама мышка движется а выделения не происходит.

```
Robot robot = new Robot();
Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle(184, 310, 410, 39);
Point start = new Point(rectangle.x, rectangle.y);
Point finish = new Point(rectangle.x + rectangle.width, rectangle.y + rectangle.height);
robot.mouseMove(start.x, start.y);
robot.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_DOWN_MASK);
robot.mouseMove(finish.x, finish.y);
robot.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON1_DOWN_MASK);
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, почему так происходит, и как это исправить? Спасибо.

Comment: У меня выделяет. Какая ОС?

Comment: @LEQADA MacOS, а у вас?

Comment: На Ubuntu работает

Comment: Попробуйте использовать `robot.mousePress(1024)`

Comment: И добавьте лучше название ОС в тело вопроса - она имеет значение. Java кроссплатформенная, но не совсем ;)

Comment: @LEQADA да, но работать приложение должно будет на Windows Server 2012, это только разработка ведется под Mac. Так что решение нужно именно кроссплатформенное, иначе не получается.